# Does elastic search keep index and document both in cache?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have gone through the [link](http://www.mkyong.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-hello-world-example/) and couple of tutorial on  elastic search(ES)
My question is does ES keep both index and documents(to be searched) under cache/memory ?

Consider I created the book in database and returned primary key is 1001. Now I store the same document under ElasticSearch.
Here is my url(`http://localhost:9200/bookstore/books/1001`) for creating book with id as 1001(1001 is primary key from DB) and below
is the document

```
    {
      "title": "Java 8 Optional In Depth",
      "category":"Java",
      "published_date":"23-FEB-2017",
      "author":"Rambabu Posa"
    }
```

My understanding:-

1. I believe it will create index on all fields(`title, category, published_date, author`) by default
2. ES store the document and index both in memory ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes
2. Yes and no. Actually the OS caches index files in RAM and plays a great role here

Comment: It is worth to mention, that before Elasticsearch creates Lucene index on the disk, all recent data stored only in the RAM. The time before all data accumulated in the RAM being dumped to the index on the disk can be configured via `refresh_interval` setting.

Comment: @dadoonet can you please elaborate point 2 ? I believe you meant both document and index both are stored in memory but it is done by OS not ES. ES just uses the OS cache. is that correct ?

Comment: Documents and indices are stored on disk within files. Files are cached by the OS when frequently read.

Comment: Is there a way I can configure ES to cache the files (instead of storing it on disk or along with storing it on disk ) ?

Comment: No. Why would you do that? You can may be mount a RAM disk and use this as the data path though

Comment: It means for first couple of times there will always be IO calls as you said `Documents and indices are stored on disk within files. Files are cached by the OS when frequently read`.  Is there a configuration where we can tell when after how many read document has to be cached as `frequently read` is bit ambiguous. Actually I am trying to understand the concept here.

Comment: I don't think there is. On elasticsearch side I mean. May be on OS cache though.

Comment: It means its is controlled by ES only when to cache and for how long it needs to be cached ?

Comment: No it's not controlled by ES. ES just writes segments on disk. Segments can contain multiple documents. Anytime you need to access a doc you need to read this segment. This is where the OS may cache the segment file.

Comment: Ok It means  ES while reading first check whether it's on OS cache or not . If found then return from cache otherwise fetch it from disk. For how long OS keep its in cache. Is it up to OS or configurable or ES has some control over it ?

Comment: No ES does not control the filesystem cache. You can independently configure this but it is a bit involved. ES will just use the OS calls to read/write segment and OS will do the check/fetch part. The caching part ES controls is for the queries, see here https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/filter-caching.html

Comment: @dadoonet Sorry for late followup question on your point `the OS caches index files in RAM and plays a great role here`. I believe index file contains the keywords(may be in sorted fashion) and document location containing it. Now when search request comes, first index file (cached by OS is searched, if applicable) otherwise
it fetched from DB. As second step,  ES will search the document_location for that keyword. One Document location is determined, ES will fetch the document
from ES DB. Is that correct ?